# Is there a way to include/render a file from outside `src` in DocPad?

Tags: include, docpad

I have a project which have a lot of useful docs outside of the `src` directory which I'd like to render as usual DocPad documents.

Examples:

- Files at the root of the project: `README.md`, `LICENSE`, `Contributing.md` and similar, which are already there and can be used in things like GitHub. I would like to reuse the content from those files to create the corresponding `readme`, `license` and `contributing` pages, or to include the contents from those files somewhere in layout or a document.
- I have a project that have some docs inside, and I'd like to render the `.md` files as DocPad documents from it by including it in `package.json`, so those files would be in `node_modules` at root.

In both those cases there are files outside of the `src/documents` that I'd like to use as partials or documents, and it seems that the partial plugin can't help me (or I couldn't find a way to make it do what I need), and the `@getCollection` can only get things from the `src/documents`.

So, the question is: Is there a way I can tell DocPad to treat some of the files/folders from the outside of the `src` folder? Do I miss something?

If not, then what would be the best way to do it as a plugin, which direction should I dig?

Comment: A source discussion for this ability inside DocPad can be found here: https://github.com/docpad/docpad/issues/878

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer would be a rather simple one: relative symbolic links. Docpad handles them perfectly.

This way, to have a symlink of README.md inside your documents, you should do this (with `pwd` of src/documents):

```
ln -s ../../README.md readme.html.md
```

Or, in case of a docs from inside one of the project's modules:

```
ln -s ../../node_modules/foobar/docs/ docs
```

Both those variants work perfectly.

---

Note: Symlinks can be tricky. Refer to these for some common gotchas:

- https://github.com/docpad/docpad/issues/878#issuecomment-53197720
- https://github.com/docpad/docpad/issues/878#issuecomment-53209674

Comment: It's pity DocPad does not support this, either natively or pluginly, I'd need solution that does not force creation of symbolic links. Anyone?

Comment: @ni5ni6 I've added an answer that shows how do this without symbolic links.

Answer (score 2):

DocPad natively supports storing documents outside of the default `src` folder. The way you do this is via the `documentsPaths` config option in the [DocPad Configuration File](http://docpad.org/docs/config/) (e.g. `docpad.coffee`). Something like this:

```
 path = require('path')
 docpadConfig = {

        documentsPaths: [
            'documents'
            path.resolve('..','data','documents')
        ]
 ....
```

Of course, where this will fall down is if you want to just include arbitrary, individual files somewhere on the file system. In such cases symlinks would be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Template helpers can also be used for this, as they can do whatever you want.

For instance, the [Bevry Learning Centre](https://github.com/bevry/learn) website uses template helpers to render arbitrary files by relative paths as code examples:

1. Template Helper: https://github.com/bevry/learn/blob/6e202638f2321eec2633d1dbeaf1078bdb953562/docpad.coffee#L244-L257
2. Tempalte using the Template Helper: https://github.com/bevry/documentation/blob/f24901251d19ec1cfa56fcee14c2c6836c0a995c/node/handsonnode/03-server.html.md.eco

If you would also like to render them, you could combine such a solution with the [Text Plugin](https://github.com/docpad/docpad-plugin-text).

The combination would be like so:

1. Template Helper in DocPad Configuration File:

   ```
   docpadConfig =
       templateData:
           readProjectPath: (relativePath) ->
               fullPath = require('path').join(__dirname, relativePath)
               return @readFullPath(fullPath)
           readRelativePath: (relativePath) ->
               fullPath = @getPath(relativePath)
               return @readFullPath(fullPath)
           readFullPath: (fullPath) ->
               result = require('fs').readFileSync(fullPath)
               if result instanceof Error
                   throw result
               else
                   return result.toString()
   ```
2. Usage of Template Helper with Text Plugin using Eco as templating engine:

   ```
   <t render="markdown"><%- @readProjectPath('README.md') %></t>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Just as a comparison between the different answers:

- Use the [paths solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34606945/130638) when you want to add entire extra directories to be included inside the DocPad database to be treated as normal by DocPad.
- Use the [sym/hard link solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25476493/130638) when you want to include specific documents or files that you would like to be treated as a DocPad document or file, with all the intelligent file parsing and document rendering, including layout, database, and caching features.
- Use the [template helper solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34621361/130638) when you want to include specific files that you do not want included in the DocPad database for whatever reason.

Made this answer a community wiki one, so it can be updated accordingly for new answers and better details.